# Formatting the output of an SQL query

Tags: sql, formatting

I am using the Solaris OS. From Solaris I'm logging into [SQL*Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL*Plus).
My database is Oracle 9i.

I am spooling the output of my query into a file. How can I get it in [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format so that I can copy it into Excel?

My query is like the follwing.

```
select name,id,location from employee;
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way out of it.
We can use concatenation here,

```
select name,id,location from employee;
```

gives us 2 different columns, but not in CSV format.

I did

```
select name||','||id||','||location from employee;
```

We get the output in a CSV format. It has just concatenated the output with commas (,).

Comment: Your solution works unless you have commas located in your data.  In those instances you will need to double quote the fields.