# TOAD Export Oracle Script To Save Data Programatically

Tags: oracle, export, toad

I have a bunch of SELECT statement scripts where I am pulling data for a bunch of different tables.  As far as exporting that data and saving it, I have to manually run each query, right click and "Save Data As" select my options, then click save.

Is there any thing I can wrap my SELECT statment programatically in so that when I run it it will automatically export and save the data eliminating the need for me to manually "Save Data As?"

[image]

Comment: How are you saving the exported data ? SQL statements ? CSV ?

Comment: I am saving the data just as a pipe deliminted flat file .txt

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can.  Toad has an automation designer that will allow you to automate and schedule the task.  Look under Utilities -- Automation Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to use [`sqlplus`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLPlus) to spool results of your select queries into a [`csv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

See this stackoverflow answer for directions:

[How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, I do not have access to sqlplus currently.  Is this possible to be done with just TOAD?

Comment: aherrick: sqlplus is distributed with oracle clients, you can download them from oracle. Since you're already using TOAD which needs an oracle client to connect to the database, you should be able to use sqlplus as well. There is no way to do this in TOAD for a number of queries automatically.