# PL/SQL procedure for generating the number of columns in a table with table_name into CSV file

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
select table_name,count(column_name) from all_tab_columns where owner ='HR'
```

This query retrieves the results, but I want the same calculation of the number of columns
in a table using a PL/SQL procedure and that output should go into a CSV file.

Comment: your question is not clear or appears to be cut off, can you clarify your problem?

Comment: i want to retrieve the no of columns present in a table using pl/sql code .. and the output should be written in a file(csv)

Comment: Start with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`, put your SELECT in appropriately, and look at the docs for the UTL_FILE package.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what didn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Create CSV version 1 (not using PL/SQL but still creates a CSV file) with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

```
set colsep ,     
set pagesize 0   
set trimspool on 
set headsep off  
set linesize 100   
set numw 10      

spool myfile.csv

select table_name,count(column_name) as cnt 
from all_tab_columns where owner ='HR' 
group by table_name);
```

Version 2 with a bit PL/SQL

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  for  c in (select table_name,count(column_name) as cnt 
             from all_tab_columns where owner ='HR' group by table_name)  
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.table_name||';'||c.cnt);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Version 3 would be using the utl_file package if you want the file server side but I was now assuming you run it in SQLplus or SQLdeveloper.

Comment: HEY THANK U..ITS VERY SIMPLE.... BUT YET GREAT MIND TO THINK..!! GOOD
AND I HAVE RETREIVED  THE OUTPUT USING UTL_FILE.TQ!! HOL

Comment: but willl i have any problem if columns are added to a table and are not analyzed???

Comment: What do you mean with not analyzed?

Comment: when table stats are gathered then only the updated or added column will be  recorded in the all_tab_columns  ryt??

Comment: Oh that is a different questions of what is in the all_tab_columns view and has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: But you know what. You misread that. When you google that table there is a entry from oracle where they talk about stats. That has nothing to do with the content of the view. ALL_TAB_COLUMNS is updated whenever a table changes. By the way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @hol....okk so no need of worrying on stats analyzing..okkk

Hey The code i am using it with utl_file.. its working fine..
but when i am combining with another proc...its getting errors???

Comment: in brief... 
select owner,table_name,sum(column_name) from all_tab_columns where data_type in number; ----- first proc (here i used curosr) and .............. next "ur proc" ---  but its giving error saying:  " table_name must be defined" ... how to resolve it??

Comment: can u give the proc by uing a cursor?? am unable to get that

Comment: can u give me ur email id to post it correctly..here i cant post it..not enough space or unable to post it for some reason.??