# How to save SQLPLUS output to text file without buffer line?

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

There are some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus) questions, but specifically do not answer my question specifically on how do you control the output of SQLPLUS queries so that it outputs all the result sets to a text file, without the buffer line, by that I mean what's held in the buffer when you use the SAVE command. For example, it's usually the first line, with a "SQL>" prompt followed by your SQL statement. How do you completely REMOVE that line and simply output (using SPOOL I presume) to a text file?

Comment: `set feedback off` and `set echo off` should do it if I'm not mistaken. All the details are in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1082570

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately still seeing the prompt line

Comment: Did you try **all** the option listed in the manual?

Comment: I know, but one of the reasons *I* ask a question is to save myself the time of trying all possibilities or searching the entire documentation base...

Comment: You don't need to *try* them. Just copy and paste the example from the manual.

Comment: The `SQL >` line won't be output if you connect silently with `sqlplus -S schema/pw@db`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL > line won't be output if you connect silently with `sqlplus -S schema/pw@db`