# Spool Command: Do not output SQL statement to file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am wanting to output a Query to a CSV file and am using the below as a small test;

```
spool c:\test.csv 
select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;
spool off;
```

but the output has the actual select statment as the first line

```
> select /*csv*/ username    user_id     created from all_users
USERNAME    USER_ID CREATED
REPORT  52  11-Sep-13
WEBFOCUS    51  18-Sep-12
```

Is there a way to prevent this?  I tried SET Heading Off thinking that might do it, but it did not change.  I am using SQL Developer an running as script.

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Developer doesn't fully honour the `set echo off` command that would (appear to) solve this in SQL*Plus.

The only workaround I've found for this is to save what you're doing as a script, e.g. `test.sql` with:

```
set echo off
spool c:\test.csv 
select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;
spool off;
```

And then from SQL Developer, only have a call to that script:

```
@test.sql
```

And run that as a script (F5).

Saving as a script file shouldn't be much of a hardship anyway for anything other than an ad hoc query; and running that with `@` instead of opening the script and running it directly is only a bit of a pain.

---

A bit of searching found the same solution on the [SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10387562), and the development team suggest it's intentional behaviour to mimic what SQL*Plus does; you need to run a script with `@` there too in order to hide the query text.

Comment: This behaviour seems to have changed in 4.2.0 (EA2); having a separate script file may no longer be necessary. May change again before the final release, of course....

Answer (score 3):

My shell script calls the sql file and executes it. The spool output had the SQL query at the beginning followed by the query result.

This did not resolve my problem:

```
set echo off
```

This resolved my problem:

```
set verify off
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who stumbles upon this (after 7+ years) ...

This works for me ... adapt it to your way of invoking sqlplus.

```
sqlplus -s / as sysdba 2>&1 > /dev/null <<EOF
  whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
  set echo off 
  set verify off
  set feedback off
  set term off
  set head off
  set pages 1000
  set lines 200

  spool /tmp/whatever.output
  
  ### Your_SQL_statement_here ###
  example: select sysdate from dual;
  example: select * from V\$LOGFILE;

  spool off
EOF
```

-s flag here is the key to not displaying the SQL statements when runing a script.

Answer (score 0):

```
set echo off
spool c:\test.csv 
select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;
spool off;
```

Comment: `set verify off  
set echo off  
set pagesize 0  
spool c:\test.csv  
select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;`   but it is still showing the first line with the select statement.  The script output in SQL Developer shows fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly export the query result with export option in the result grig.
    This export has various options to export. I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Exec the query in TOAD or SQL DEVELOPER

```
---select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;
```

Save in .SQL format in "C" drive

```
--- x.sql
```

execute command

```
---- set serveroutput on
     spool y.csv
     @c:\x.sql
     spool off;
```