# Automatically export result sets into csv

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to run several queries on an `oracle 11g database`, within `SQLDeveloper 3.1`.

For example:

```
select * from product;
select * from customer;
select * from prices;
```

At the moment I am exporting the resultsets "per hand", I simply right-click`onto the result and then`export` it.

I would like to automatically save the resultset of each query in a specific folder.

Any recommendation how I could do that?

**UPDATE**

I tried using the `csv` and als the `txt` extesion of `testFile`:

```
spool C:\Users\User\Desktop\testFile.csv --I tried also .txt extension here!!!

set colsep ';'

select * from product;

spool off;
```

However, when I open the file I get for csv and txt the following result:

```
> set colsep '
> select * from product
```

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directly export a query to CSV using SQL Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448322/directly-export-a-query-to-csv-using-sql-developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set echo off

set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on

spool output.csv

select  columnA || ',' || columnB || ',' || ...... 
from table 
where ...

spool off;
exit 0;
```

Then create a shell script that calls the sql file

```
sqlplus >/dev/null 2>&1 "user/pass@DATABASE" << EOF

whenever sqlerror exit 1

@file.sql
EOF
```

UPDATE just saw you are on windows, same principle still applies, you probably will need to use PowerShell

Comment: Thx for your answer! The problem is that I do not have sqlplus installed on the computer I am using and I do not have sufficent access rights. I ony have SQLDeveloper available.

Comment: the SQL script should still work in SQLDeveloper you just cant make it run automaticaly.

Comment: A second option is to create a PLSQL procedure that exports to directory, but that is abit more complicated. can you create procedures and oracle directories ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spool, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm

```
spool OutFile.txt
select row1||','||row2... from product; --format you prefer
spool off;
```

Comment: Thx foryour answer! However, this does not work for me. Please have a look at my update!