# Export data from Oracle to CSV

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I am using *Oracle 12c* on an instance of *Amazon Web Services EC2*.

I want to export data from one Oracle table with 5M records to a local folder in CSV format.

Is there a script or program to do that quickly in Redhat/bash environment?

I am looking for minimal installation and setup.

Comment: use the search - there must be a dozen variations of this question already covered, here's just one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448322/directly-export-a-query-to-csv-using-sql-developer/19448806

Answer (score 1):

You want it quickly? How about a simple SPOOL SQLPlus command? You can make it prettier using different SET commands (type HELP SET on SQLPlus command prompt), but the general idea is as follows:

```
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL> spool emp.csv
SQL> select employee_id, first_name, last_name
  2  from employees
  3  where rownum < 5;

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME          ,LAST_NAME
-----------,--------------------,-------------------------
        100,Steven              ,King
        101,Neena               ,Kochhar
        102,Lex                 ,De Haan
        103,Alexander           ,Hunold

SQL> spool off;
SQL> $type emp.csv
SQL> select employee_id, first_name, last_name
  2  from employees
  3  where rownum < 5;

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME          ,LAST_NAME
-----------,--------------------,-------------------------
        100,Steven              ,King
        101,Neena               ,Kochhar
        102,Lex                 ,De Haan
        103,Alexander           ,Hunold

SQL> spool off;

SQL>
```

[EDITED by LF, after seeing OP's comment]

OK then, as you didn't take that effort and examine what SET offers, here you go: if you want to get a clean output (no headings, underlines, SELECT command, etc.), create a SQL file (let's name it SP.SQL):

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET LINESIZE 9999
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TIMING OFF
SET TIME OFF
SET COLSEP ','
SPOOL emp.csv

SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name
FROM employees
WHERE rownum < 5;

SPOOL OFF
```

Now connect to SQLPlus and run that script:

```
SQL> @sp
        100,Steven              ,King
        101,Neena               ,Kochhar
        102,Lex                 ,De Haan
        103,Alexander           ,Hunold
SQL>
```

Finally, if you take a look at EMP.CSV, you'll see that it is nice and clean.

Satisfied?

Comment: This was not giving exact CSV format as output.. There was a lot of headers, dashes, column dividers etc.. Is there a way to get a clean CSV format? Thanks..