# selecting huge data in oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I have to select data form a table under Oracle 10.The statement I have simply used is

```
select * from table_name;
```

After the execution of the statement it first fetches 50 rows.
Thenafter I just select ctrl+A to select all the rows and export it to a csv file.
But it is taking a lot of time.
Is there a better way to fetch all the rows and capture the data to csv?

Comment: You can directly spool your query to the disk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033943/spool-command-do-not-output-sql-statement-to-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle SQL Developer tool connect to database and right click on Table which is the table you want export the data then select **Export** option there you can select **Format as CSV**
or
After select * from table_name; go to result then right mouse click, then select Export then select **Format as CSV** and select the path where you want save then then **Next** then **Finish**

Comment: I asked the same.Currently following this technique only.Asked for a better approach.