# Hide SQL word in the sqlplus file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to hide/remove the "SSQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7 " in the file raw.txt

my steps

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
    set heading off
    set pagesize 0
    set feedback off
    set echo off
    set colsep "|"

    select 
    v_tls_equipment_logon_ct2.equipment_id,v_tls_equipment_logon_ct2.user_type_c,v_tls_equipment_logon_ct2.logon_dt,
    tls_user.user_m,tls_user.user_id,tls_user.emp_n,tls_user.org_c 
    from 
    v_tls_equipment_logon_ct2
    INNER JOIN tls_user
    ON v_tls_equipment_logon_ct2.user_id = tls_user.user_id;
```

sending

```
email="abcd1234@gmail.com dsasd@gmail.com.com"

DBpath=/opt/util/sqlplus10g
interFile=/archive/equipment/EI/Jovan/dataMinerUserLogon/raw.txt
FILEPATHDATEFORMAT=`TZ=GMT-8 date +%Y%m%d%H`
FILENAME=logonDetails_${FILEPATHDATEFORMAT}.csv
FILEDIR="/archive/equipment/EI/Jovan/dataMinerUserLogon/${FILENAME}"
EMAILBODY="/archive/operations/EI/scripts/eisupport_menu/EQPT-VERSION/WOSPC/CT3/output/SystemGeneratedMessageTemplate.txt"


#Execute SQL file
${DBpath} < /archive/equipment/EI/Jovan/dataMinerUserLogon/logonuser.sql > ${interFile} 
awk 'NR > 17 { print }' < ${interFile} > ${FILEDIR}
```

my result

```
SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7  PPM417                             |2  |2018 JUN 20 09:24:31      |BALASUBRAMANIAM A/L MANICKAM                                                              |CL$BAM          |F8031299R              |PSA
```

Comment: I don't see, in your code, where you are sending anything to a .txt file. Please show us ALL your code, otherwise we can't help you properly.

Comment: @mathguy Yup, sorry i've added

Comment: You may want to take a look at this. It's a few years old, but I believe things haven't changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033943/spool-command-do-not-output-sql-statement-to-file

Comment: I always have trouble remembering which SQLPlus setting controls which output.  I think you may want to add `set termout off` to your script.  (As general practice, you may also want to use `set verify off` when sending output to a file, but I don't think that is relevant to this example.)

Answer (score 3):

To suppress the SQL prompts, you should use the `-silent` option to the sqlplus executable.  It can be abbreviated to `-s`.

Comment: Where do i put it?

Comment: On the SQL*Plus command line. [See (somewhat dated) docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1005759) - I don't think much has changed. Best of luck.

Comment: so i just do a " sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF " at my scripts? @BobJarvis

Comment: @KaushikNayak Then where should i put it?

Comment: @BinQuan - it doesn't go inside your .sql script file; it goes in your shell script, so `${DBpath} -s < /archive...`. (Presumably the first two lines of that are file are your credentials; if you add `/nolog` then those woudl change to an explicit `connect` command.)

Answer (score 1):

[The `-s` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#sthref223) is part of the `sqlplus` (or in your case, `sqlplus10g`) command:

> Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus. If you omit username or password, SQL*Plus prompts for them, but the prompts are not visible! Use `SILENT` to invoke SQL*Plus within another program so that the use of SQL*Plus is invisible to the user.

That flag needs to be in your shell script where the program is invoked, not in the SQL script file:

```
#Execute SQL file
${DBpath} -s < /archive/equipment/EI/Jovan/dataMinerUserLogon/logonuser.sql > ${interFile}
```

You've also mentioned the `/nolog` option; that prevents SQL*Plus from promoting for credentials on startup, and you would have to connect explicitly. In an interactive session that would look like:

```
> sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jun 20 10:13:45 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL>
```

Your current code implies the first two line of your SQL script are the username and password you want to connect as:

```
your_username
your_password
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
...
```

If you add the `/nolog` option as well:

```
#Execute SQL file
${DBpath} -s /nolog < /archive/equipment/EI/Jovan/dataMinerUserLogon/logonuser.sql > ${interFile}
```

then the SQL file would have to change to:

```
connect your_username/your_password
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
...
```

Embedding credentials in a file obviously isn't very secure either way, of course.