# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected using shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql

there are so many post about this error. However i am not able to resolve my code. i am trying to run this SQl in shell script, but it is giving me this error. ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

```
SELECT
  wrk.WO_ID,
  srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO,
  srq.ASDL_CMD,
  srq.HOST_CLLI                                    AS NEP,
  MIN(srq.START_DTS)                               AS start_dt,
  MAX(srq.COMP_DTS)                                AS comp_dt,
  ((MAX(srq.COMP_DTS)-MIN(srq.START_DTS)) * 86400) AS proc_time
FROM
  SARMPRD1.TBL_ASDL_LOG srq,
  sarmprd1.tbl_wrk_ord wrk
WHERE
  srq.srq_id      = wrk.srq_id
AND srq.start_dts > TRUNC(sysdate) + 7.5/24
AND wrk.WO_STAT   = '104'
GROUP BY
  wrk.WO_ID,
  srq.SRQ_ID,
  srq.ASDL_UNID,
  srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO,
  srq.ASDL_CMD,
  HOST_CLLI
ORDER BY
  proc_time DESC;
```

Can anyone please help me where is the problem?

Comment: SQL itself looks good, i'd say that there will be problem with escaping. Is this a standalone file or is it actually in shell script ? If yes, paste also the surrounding shell code.

Comment: here is the complete code..

Comment: select 'WO_ID, SEQ_NO, ASDL,NE, START_TIME, COMP_DT, PROC_TIME' from sys.dual;
SELECT wrk.WO_ID||','||srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO||','||srq.ASDL_CMD||','||srq.HOST_CLLI As NEP||','||min(srq.START_DTS) as start_dt||','||max(srq.COMP_DTS) as comp_dt||','||((max(srq.COMP_DTS)-min(srq.START_DTS)) * 86400) as proc_time FROM SARMPRD1.TBL_ASDL_LOG srq, sarmprd1.tbl_wrk_ord wrk where srq.srq_id = wrk.srq_id and srq.start_dts > trunc(sysdate) + 7.5/24 and wrk.WO_STAT = '104' group by wrk.WO_ID, srq.SRQ_ID, srq.ASDL_UNID, srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO, srq.ASDL_CMD,HOST_CLLI order by proc_time desc;
spool off

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in the concatenation operator. Since you concatenate all the columns, you cannot use 'AS NEP', 'AS START_DT', etc. Remove those and it will work fine, remember that you are outputting practicaly only one column, so multiple aliases don't work.

For an useful alternative, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus).

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, with concatenate operator ...

here's your original:

```
select 'WO_ID, SEQ_NO, ASDL,NE, START_TIME, COMP_DT, PROC_TIME' from sys.dual; 
SELECT wrk.WO_ID||','||srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO||','||srq.ASDL_CMD||','||srq.HOST_CLLI As NEP||','||min(srq.START_DTS) as start_dt||','||max(srq.COMP_DTS) as comp_dt||','||((max(srq.COMP_DTS)-min(srq.START_DTS)) * 86400) as proc_time FROM SARMPRD1.TBL_ASDL_LOG srq, sarmprd1.tbl_wrk_ord wrk where srq.srq_id = wrk.srq_id and srq.start_dts > trunc(sysdate) + 7.5/24 and wrk.WO_STAT = '104' group by wrk.WO_ID, srq.SRQ_ID, srq.ASDL_UNID, srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO, srq.ASDL_CMD,HOST_CLLI order by proc_time desc
```

Try this:

```
select 'WO_ID, SEQ_NO, ASDL,NE, START_TIME, COMP_DT, PROC_TIME' from sys.dual; 
SELECT wrk.WO_ID||','||srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO||','||srq.ASDL_CMD||','||srq.HOST_CLLI As NEP||','||min(srq.START_DTS) as start_dt,
    max(srq.COMP_DTS) as comp_dt,
    ((max(srq.COMP_DTS)-min(srq.START_DTS)) * 86400) as proc_time 
FROM SARMPRD1.TBL_ASDL_LOG srq, sarmprd1.tbl_wrk_ord wrk 
where srq.srq_id = wrk.srq_id 
  and srq.start_dts > trunc(sysdate) + 7.5/24 
  and wrk.WO_STAT = '104' 
group by wrk.WO_ID, srq.SRQ_ID, srq.ASDL_UNID, srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO, srq.ASDL_CMD,HOST_CLLI 
order by proc_time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the solution to your problem, but here is a suggestion:

Create a new script with just a few items from your original script in it. Run it and see if it works. If so, add a bit more code and verify that works. Continue doing this until it fails. The problem line should then be easily identified.