# Insert rows from a table in another database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can rows be inserted into a table from a table in a remote database?

We currently have a stored procedure which does this using a database link. However, we are having to delete the link because our company policy doesn't allow their usage.

```
begin
    ...
    execute immediate 'insert into '|| table_name
                     || ' (select * from schema_name.'|| table_name ||'@link)';
    ...
end;
```

I'm unable to use the `COPY` command as it appears to be not recognized.

```
COPY FROM username/pwd@SID
  insert into table_name using (select *
                                from table_name);
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
00926. 00000 -  "missing VALUES keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm#634424) SQL Plus page, `COPY` command is now obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Query syntax is slightly wrong, and you just need to specify `INSERT/REPLACE/CREATE` .. and `INTO` is *NOT* needed.

COPY is not obsolete, but it ends up with some encoding [issues](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1546206316314).
You would use the line continuation character to get around that.

```
COPY 
  FROM username/pwd@SID 
  TO username/pass@SID2
  insert 
 table_name 
 using 
    select * from schema_name.table_name;
```

You can also, download the table data into a text file, and use [`SQL*Loader`](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlloader.html) to load the data into the another Database.

I prefer the SQL*Loader option! Since maintenance is easy!

For download, 
- you can either use SPOOL with delimiter option as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)
- Write a Pro*C/PLSQL to output the data into a File ([Method 4](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_15ody.htm) in Pro*C, OR select column names from `dba_columns`))

Comment: +1 for Sql *Loader. There is also [data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm) that can be used with the same effect.

Comment: @OracleUser Are there any other options other than COPY? I learned that COPY is an SQL Plus command and hence cannot be used in a stored procedure. The stored procedure is on a cron job and hence the SQL Loader option doesn't fit the situation.