# Return number of records in SQL select union

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a select query so that it meets a certain format. I need the string "Record Count" in first row. Then I also need the number of rows in second column row 1. Then I need to union it with another query

```
Record Count    125 
2134123
```

Here's what it looks like for sample in a csv that I want the output to appear as

```
Record Count,125
99902064
12312312
```

I tried the following code

```
SELECT 'Record Count', count(select loginid
from employees)
FROM dual
union
select loginid
from employees
```

When I do this is puts the word record count in all the rows. I only want Record Count in row 1 and then next column have actual #. I was also considering just changing the column header to be "Record Count" but I couldn't figure out how to make the next column header a # i.e. use count(*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need rows in a particular order, then you need to use `order by`.  Here is one method:

```
select loginid, cnt
FROM (SELECT 'Record Count' as loginid, (select count(loginid) from employees) as cnt, 1 as ordering
      FROM dual
      union all
      select loginid, NULL, 2
      from employees
     ) t
order by ordering;
```

The subqueries in a `union` should also have the same columns, and the columns should be given names.  And, I'm not aware that you can use a subquery as the argument to `count()`.

For this form, this is a better way to write the query:

```
select loginid, cnt
FROM (SELECT 'Record Count' as loginid, count(loginid) as cnt, 1 as ordering
      FROM employees
      union all
      select loginid, NULL, 2
      from employees
     ) t
order by ordering;
```

Comment: in this case `record count` will be always the first row because is the first query in the union, i think

Comment: @Aramillo - in this version it probably will be, because it has `union all` rather than just `union` so there is no sort/merge step. In your version it's likely to be out of order, depending on the session NLS sort settings. But even with `union all`, I don't think the order is guaranteed; the behaviour could change in the future, so it's safer to explicitly order it.

Comment: Sorry @AlexPoole, but i think union and union all works fetching rows depending of the order of the querys, but if you say this, i think i have to deep in this topic, thanks for the tip

Comment: @Aramillo - compare the outputs [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/223); and with more values [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/227). The `union` values are sorted, as part of the duplicate-elimination process.

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Gordon this solution worked for me great i was stuck on this for awhile saved me from bashing my head on keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the same removing the union using sqlplus spool.

Example of how to spool [How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

```
SELECT 'Record Count'|| ','|| count(select loginid
 from employees)
 FROM dual;
 select loginid
 from employees;
```

Comment: by experience we use this kind of script in sqlplus to generate csv files