# Oracle to Neo4j Sync

Tags: oracle, neo4j, nosql

Do we have any utility to sync data between Oracle  & Neo4J database. I want to use Neo4j in readonly mode & all writes will happen to oracle DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on how often you want to have the data synced.  Are you looking for a periodic sync/ETL process (say hourly or daily), or are looking for live updates into Neo4j?

I'm not aware of tools designed for this, but it's not terribly difficult to script yourself.

A periodic sync is obviously easiest.  You can do that directly using the Java API and connecting via JDBC to Oracle.  You could also just dump the data from Oracle as a CSV and import into Neo4j.  This would be done similiarly to how data is imported from PostreSQL in this article: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/

There is a SO response for exporting data from Oracle using sqlplus/spool:
[How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

If you're looking for live syncing, you'd probably do this either through monitoring the transaction log or by adding triggers onto your tables, depending on the complexity of your data.

Comment: thanks for your response. I was looking for hourly sync.