# How do I spool to a CSV file using SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this kind of script that i want to spool the final output to a csv file. can you please help?

```
with first_sub as
select etc
,
second_sub as
select etc

select first_column from first_sub* first_column from second_sub etc.
```

......................................
..basically, i have 2 or more sub queries that i do maths on in my 'final query'
what i need is to be able to spool the output as a csv.

sorry but im not able to post any specific code

ok, to clarify, i CAN ALREADY spool a 'Simple' query 
i.e `select *from employees'

what i have is like this

```
    with sub_1 as 
    select * from employees
    ,
    sub_2 as 
    select * from other_employees

select something from sub1 * something_else from sub_2
```

The last bit is what i want to take out to a .csv file please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please first post a correct query, then we can handle the csv question. Also, please post the type of the fields you need to spool ( do you have dates, numbers, ...?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

Comment: It always helps to share correct query and as much information as possible ...

Answer (score 2):

-- SQL developer
You can use `/*csv*/` hint in SQL developer. As @Aleksej suggested, you can see the linked thread for further options.

```
select /*csv*/ * from employees;
```

--SQL Plus

```
set feedback off
set heading on
set underline off
set colsep ','

spool 'mytab.csv'
select * from tab;
spool off
```

Comment: that SQLPlus code sample will also run in SQL Developer, sans the set underline