# How do I create a file from a result set?

Tags: linux, windows, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm using Oracle 11g

I'm trying to create a flat file (CSV or TXT) from a result set but am struggling on where to even start. It seems like I have to create a stored proc and use `UTL_FILE`. After doing some research, I have two questions:

1. Where does the file get created? According to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/how-to-create-script-file-with-pl-sql) I need to get access to the Oracle user directory, but where is that on a Windows and Linux environment? I have to test on Windows , and the script will eventually be on a Linux environment.
2. What would be the basic format of a SQL script to create the aforementioned file, and load data into it from a fairly basic `SELECT` query? I'm not seeing a `UTL_FILE` function to write the records to the file; do I have to iterate through the entire result set and use `PUT` or can I somehow just push the entire result to a file?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm  You have to iterate through the result set. UTL_FILE knows nothing about your records.  It is a low-level package.

Comment: I did, but maybe I should be a bit more clear: is that `oracle\admin` directory on the server? How do I create a directory and file on the client machine? If that `oracle\admin` directory actually is on the client machine, where is it? I don't see any folder with that name anywhere

Comment: You have to create the physical directory from the OS (ie, md or mkdir ) if it does not exist on the server.  You did read the documenation, where is says, "A directory object specifies an alias for a directory **on the server file system** "  You cannot create files on the client machine.  Oracle knows nothing about your client machine.

Comment: Ah, I thought "on the server file system" meant on the server where Oracle lived. So it looks like even to create files or run a command like `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY test as 'c:\users\me\testing' that I need privileges from Oracle to even run that

Comment: Yes, it DOES mean on the server where Oracle lives.

Answer (score 2):

I think using "spool" can do the trick.

Check this out https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9518534700346581975

And more information is here http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sqlplus_spool.htm

The file will get created in the directory where you launch sqlplus from.

Comment: Yeah, I came across spool too. Are there other alternatives without `spool`? Not sure if sqlplus will be installed on the client machine to allow me to use `spool`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Developer you can create a view for your query. Right click view in schema browser and choose export and export as csv.

But personally I would go for spool as previous answer said. SQL Plus is most basic client so I don't believe you won't have it.

Comment: I need to automate this process eventually. Is there a way to do what you mentioned programatically? Also, I don't think we'll have SQL Plus. Most likely going to be SQL Developer on the machine

Comment: @simplycoding I'd go for SQL*Plus and spool if you need it automated. That's simplest and easiest to maintain. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus

Comment: Does SQL*Plus come with every Oracle client installation?

Comment: Seems like it does... Just ran the command on my Windows machine's cmd prompt, and it opened

Comment: I think every client contain SQL*Plus. You can also always use basic instantclient. @simplycoding

Comment: It is installed by default, but depending on your enterprise security protocols, may be removed, as it is a gateway to the database.