# How to use spool in Plsql developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, spool

I was wondering if we could use `spool` in Plsql developer. I am currently running a query in plsql developer which is resulting in a result set of 1 million rows. I need to export that data to an excel file but when I am selecting the columns and right clicking on the data to copy it to the excel file, it copies only 10 or 11 rows, To load all the rows, I need to press the downward arrow in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HysbR.png)

and it takes so much time to load. I was wondering if there is any easy way I could export my huge amount of data directly to an excel file in plsql developer?

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL*Plus commands work in a PLSQL Dev Command window. `spool` does. Of course, spooling 1000000 rows of data is going to take a long time.

Plus you'll need to handle the CSV formatting manually, with other SQL*Plus commands. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643137/146325).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ORA_EXCEL package for export data from sql developer in excel format.

Please visit this site :
https://www.oraexcel.com/examples

Comment: You should make it clear that ORA_EXCEL is a licensed product before suggesting people use it.