# how to use set null and concatenate operator together in Oracle?

Tags: bash, oracle, shell

I am trying to export data from Oracle into CSV with the below commands:

```
SET ECHO OFF 
SET NEWPAGE 0 
SET SPACE 0 
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET FEED OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET null NULL
SPOOL STUDENT.CSV
SELECT ID ||’,’|| NAME ||’,’|| ADMISSION_DATE FROM STUDENT; 
SPOOL OFF;
```

However, when using the concatenate operator(||','||) and set null NULL option together, it keeps the null value as a blank string (‘’) in CSV file instead of replacing it with NULL.

Can someone please tell how to use set null and concatenate operator together?

Comment: You need another tag to indicate *what* shell you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Plus commands (like `set null`) can't help in this case, since the null value is already gone by the time SQL*Plus can see the data.

```
set null NULL
select 'a' || null || 'b' from dual; -- returns "ab"
```

If you want to replace null values, you have to do it *before* concatenating. So you'll need to wrap all of your nullable columns in NVLs, e.g.

```
select 'a' || nvl(null, 'NULL') || 'b' from dual; -- returns "aNULLb"
```

Alternately, you could try using `colsep` [to put the commas in your CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus), but that adds a bunch of whitespace that you might not want.

```
set null NULL
set colsep ,
select 'a', null, 'b' from dual; -- returns "a  ,NULL,b  "
```

If you have the option of switching to Oracle's SQLcl client, [it makes it much easier](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-format-query-results-with-the-set-sqlformat-command) to generate correct CSV files from queries.

```
set null NULL
select /*csv*/ 'a', null, 'b' from dual; -- returns "a","NULL","b"
```