# SQLPLUS - ORACLE 12 - Trim extra columns white space

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, trim, space, spool

I've a problem with a sqlplus spool (oracle 12c/18c).
I want trim extra white space in columns.

This is the expected result

```
01JHON BROWN  30RED    
02MARIO ROSSI 25WHITE
```

this is my result

```
01    JHON BROWN       30        RED         
02    MARIO ROSSI      25        WHITE
```

this is the sql code

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET LINESIZE 2000
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TIME OFF
SET TIMING OFF
SET COLSEP ''
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYYMMDD';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,';

spool pippo.txt

SELECT TRIM(NUM), RPAD(NAME,12), TRIM(AGE), RPAD(COLOR,7)
FROM PLUTO;

spool off
exit
```

THX

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove extra space *between* columns, including those between 2nd and 3rd?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how column formatting works with `spool` - each row's values are padded to the full width of the columns. [See this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus) to get an idea of your options.

If you don't want any spaces between column values, you'll generally have to concatenate them into a single column, e.g.

```
SELECT TRIM(NUM) || RPAD(NAME,12) || TRIM(AGE) || RPAD(COLOR,7)
FROM PLUTO;
```