# How to export multiple tables in oracle into multiple .csv files in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to export multiple tables to individual .csv files (approximately 70 tables need to be exported) in oracle SQL Developer. As of right now, I am running through this process

Run Query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

From the result window, click "Export Query Results", choosing the encoding and delimiter and saving it as a .csv

This is a lengthy process, and takes around a minute per table (lots of information!), I can't help but think there has to be an easier, more efficient way of doing this. I just can't find any information.

Comment: Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer and Oracle SQL Developer are **two different products**. Please ensure your tags are consistent with the text of your question.

Comment: PLSQL Developer or SQL Developer - very different products. In SQL Devleoper, use the Database Export feature under Tools, select your tables, directory, and file format (CSV) .

Comment: This is a tool for automatically uploading data to csv files https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_export_dir_tables.ps1.

Comment: Corrected the Tool. I am currenty using oracle sql developer. I can connect to the oracle database only using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools - Database Export

Pick your file format (csv) and directory.

[image]

I have Excel shown in the picture, but there's a dozen formats to choose from, including delimited and CSV. If you want European CSV (;), pick delimited and change the delimiter to ;

Then pick your 70 tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for mass table export is not to use the embedded SQL Developper export tool, but use the SPOOL SQL option.

you can check here how to generate SPOOL files:
[How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)