# Export to Excel from within sql script - is it possible?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, toad

In Toad for Oracle, I know how to select a row of data and export that to an Excel file or Excel instance.

Is there any way I can do the same thing from within a sql script, run through an editor window or via sqlplus ?

I have used the spool command to get a text file, though that is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: csvs are possible, so use that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus

Comment: In sqldeveloper (FREE from Oracle) you may export to .csv or Excel a data set returned by a select. As for TOAD, I'm not sure about export to excel, but it certainly can export to .csv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

Comment: You could spool to csv as mentioned in the other comments and then use a csv to xls converter to do the conversion for you automatically.